# can I define a fixed point type for elements?

Tags: dfdl

DFDL allows for certain tags to have an attribute like `type="unsignedint16"` - but what I really have in my data is a fixed point number - I know DFDL allows for flexible representation of numbers parsed from text, but I don't know how to specify the way binary numbers should be parsed. especially for (potentially negative) fixed point numbers.